# jquery.tooltip to jqueryUI 1.9.0 missing showBody

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I am working on upgrading to jQueryUI 1.9.0 and I have jquery.tooltip that I'd like to transition to the tooltips that are now in jQueryUI.  The one problem is that jQueryUI tooltips do not have the showBody option.  Is there a quick way to add that capability in there?

http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/
http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/
http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/

I'm thinking I could write a callback attached to the content option to parse out the delimited data I want (e.g. default delimiter could be " - ", which is what it is in the "old" tooltip plugin) and break up into h3 (content before delimiter) and div (content after delimiter).

before I go too far down this road, I want to bounce it off the community to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel and something like this doesn't already exist in the jQueryUI tooltip and I just missed it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ed.S.'s solution:

> I tried the following and it works!  Leaving the post here for others
>   who may need the same functionality.
>
> ```
> $("#demoSelect").tooltip({
>     track: true,
>     content: function () {
>         var arrContent = $(this).attr('title').split(' - ');
>         var data = '<h3>' + arrContent[0] + '</h3><div>' + arrContent[1] + '</div>';
>         return data;
>     }
> });
> ```